# About codes over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: complexity-theory, coding-theory, error-correcting-codes, code-generation

I was looking through these [notes](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/FT02/) but I am not sure I can locate the answer to these questions of mine - it would be great if someone can just even point out what to look for!

- So any set of binary vectors can be seen as "code"?
- Let $M$ be a $d\times m$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and let $X(M)$ be the graph on the binary vectors of length $d$, where two vectors are adjacent if their difference is a column of $M$. (does this mean that before comparing when one is taking a bit-wise difference of the vectors one is equating $-1$ to $1$ as would be inside $\mathbb{F}_2$?)

  Does this above construction have a name? Any motivations?
- What is this NP-hard question about finding a "minimum weight code" among a set of binary vectors? Can someone kindly give the precise definition?

Comment: Please post only one question per post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A binary code is a set of vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ for some $n$.
2. Presumably the context in which you encountered this construction is a motivation for it. It's a particular case of a more general construction known as a *Cayley graph*, though perhaps this particular case has a specific name. You are right that all arithmetic is done in $\mathbb{F}_2$.
3. There are several NP-complete problems related to codes; Madhu Sudan has an entire lecture on these. One of them is, given a generator matrix for a linear code, determine the minimum weight of a non-zero codeword (i.e., the minimum distance).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22714/discussion-on-answer-by-yuval-filmus-about-codes-over-mathbbf-2).